How to animate horizontally using scaleIn/Out in a custom composable? Jetpack Compose
I wanted to animate my search bar size from left to the right when it appears (only X axis)
AnimatedContent(
    targetState = isSearchBarVisible,
) { targetState ->
    if (targetState) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(
                    start = screenWidth * 0.08f,
                    end = 16.dp,
                    top = 8.dp,
                    bottom = 8.dp
                ),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            SearchBar(
                hint = "Buscar oração",
                onTextChange = { newText -> searchText = newText },
                onSearchClicked = { focusManager.clearFocus() },
                onBackClicked = {
                    isSearchBarVisible = false
                    searchText = ""
                },
                focusRequester = focusRequester
            )
        }

I tried using AnimatedVisibility and .animateContentSize(), but scaleIn/Out from AnimatedVisibility has a Y axis, and .animateContentSize() depends on an already shown composable changing its size, which is not my case (my searchbar is invoked only when the user clicks on the search icon)

One of the you can achieve that is by using ContentTransform. Try providing a transitionSpec. Here's a starter transitionSpec = { (slideInHorizontally() + scaleIn()).togetherWith(slideOutHorizontally() + scaleOut()) }
